# Eloquent method all() undefined

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi i am learning laravel. recently i am facing a problem. It seems eloquent method are not inherited properly. When i tried to fetch all the data from a table in my controller index method, it shows "Call to undefined method Category::all()" .. It is something irritating that i never faced before as i did code earlier in the similar way. I pasted my code below. Experts need ur attention pls.

Model:

```
<?php

class Category extends \Eloquent {
    //protected $fillable = [];

    protected $table = 'categories';

    public static function getCategory($category){

        $category->category = $category['category'];
        $category->save();

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    // get all the inputs
    $categories = Category::all();

    // load the view and pass the inputs
    return View::make('manage-category')
        ->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

views:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select name='category' class="table-group-action-input form-control" name="product[status]">
        <option>Select</option>
        @if( isset($categories))
            @foreach($categories as $categories)
                <option value="{{ $categories->id }}">{{ $categories->category }}</option>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </select>
</div>
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/manage-category','CategoryController@index');
```

Comment: Two things I could think of is that you have alias removed in ```app/config/app.php``` pointing to Eloquent model class or you have defined some other alias called ```Category``` which points to another class. Try ```$class = new ReflectionClass('Category');``` and try to dump some of informations using http://php.net/manual/pl/class.reflectionclass.php to check if your ```Category``` class is indeed the one you want to use.

Comment: however i didn't make any change in app.php .. I checked my app.php file also .. u can see it - pastebin.com/qZEhmxbw

Comment: Do you use any packages? Your code seems fine to me.

Comment: I integrated a artisan command 'generate' that's it. @nozzlement

category::get() shows the same thing. -- limonte

Comment: have you done composer update and composer dump-autoload? Just in case if its related to autoloader issue

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your composer autoload definition is outdated and hence your controller is not finding the class Category. You should try running `composer dump-autoload` command from your project directory and see whether it fixes your issue, before investigating more.

Please note, Laravel 4 doesn't autoload your models (or any non-controller library classes that are added later), so every time you are adding a model class in your project, you have to run `composer dump-autoload` command from your project directory.

Comment: thanks for ur reply .. though i fixed it. Just refresh my all the migrations and regenerate them. But your suggestion is great. If I generate model by cli .. then i have to run composer dump-autoload ??

Comment: I think yes. You should run `composer dump-autoload` whenever you add non-controller files, regardless those files were create via artisan commands or manually.